# Avoid the same warning message for the second time on maximum length reached

Tags: delphi

I have this :

```
procedure TForm1.cxMemo1PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not  (trim(cxmemo1.lines.Text) = '')  then begin
    AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Animate :=True;
    AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Visible :=True;
    cxlabel1.Visible:=True;
    cxlabel1.caption := 'Letters left : ' + inttostr(cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength - Length(cxmemo1.Text));
    if Length(cxMemo1.Text) = cxMemo1.Properties.MaxLength then    //when maximum lenght reached
      if MessageDlg(
        'Maximum lenght reached (200).'+ #13#10 +'Extend maximum lenght to 500?',
        mtWarning, 
        [mbNo, mbYes], 
        0) = mrYes then
          cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength:=500;
    cxlabel1.caption := 'Letters left : ' + inttostr(cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength - Length(cxmemo1.Text));
  end else  begin
    AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Animate :=False;
    AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Visible :=False;
    cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength:=200 ;
    cxlabel1.Visible:=False;
  end;
end;
```

How can I avoid the display of the warning message if the user reaches 500 characters in the memo or at least tell him that the maximum bonus (500) has already been reached ?

Comment: If length is 500, then use another text in the message dialog.

Comment: lenght is only temporary.

Comment: But 500 is a fixed value. If the memo text length has reached 500 characters, you can test for that before issuing the message dialog and take other actions.

Comment: Make the warning parameterized, using `Format('Length exceeded %d, extend to %d?', [MaxLength, NewLength])`. If the user accepts, then `MaxLength := NewLength;` where NewLength is calculated as MaxLength + 200 or some percent.

Comment: Use a `case` statement to separate the messages, actions to take in the two situations: `if Length(cxMemo1.Text) = cxMemo1.Properties.MaxLength then
   begin
      case cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength of
        200: ;{Show message and take actions for 200 reached}
        500: ;{Show message and take actions for 500 reached}
      end;
    end;`

Comment: Nice idea Tom...will use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, redone ...

```
procedure TForm1.cxMemo1PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
if not  (trim(cxmemo1.lines.Text) = '')  then  begin
AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Animate :=True;
AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Visible :=True;
cxlabel1.Visible:=True;
cxlabel1.caption := 'Letters left : ' + inttostr(cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength - Length(cxmemo1.Text));
end else begin
AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Animate :=False;
AdvSmoothWin8Marquee1.Visible :=False;
cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength:=200 ;
cxlabel1.Visible:=False;
end;
  if Length(cxMemo1.Text) = cxMemo1.Properties.MaxLength then begin
  case cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength of
  200:
  if MessageDlg('Maximum lenght reached (200).'+ #13#10 +'Extend memo maximum lenght to 400?',
  mtWarning, [mbNo, mbYes], 0) = mrYes then  begin
  cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength:=400;
  cxlabel1.caption := 'Letters left : ' + inttostr(cxmemo1.Properties.MaxLength - Length(cxmemo1.Text));
  end;
  400: 
  ShowMessage('No more extensions.');
  end;
  end;
  end;
end;
```